# How can I check error code in Gnome/gjs/Gio

Tags: javascript, gnome, gio, gjs

This doesn't work (nothing happens when the directory exists):

```
let s_dir = Gio.file_new_for_path("./S1");
try {
        s_dir.make_directory(null);
} catch(e) {
        if(e == Gio.IOErrorEnum.EXISTS)
            print(e);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`GLib.Error.matches()`](http://devdocs.baznga.org/glib20~2.50.0/glib.error#method-matches) method:

```
let s_dir = Gio.file_new_for_path("./S1");
try {
        s_dir.make_directory(null);
} catch(e) {
        if (e.matches (Gio.IOErrorEnum, Gio.IOErrorEnum.EXISTS)
            print(e);
}
```